# Does the scope change when we change to other page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created a variable with `$scope` in my controller. Apparently, that `$scope` will be applied (available) to that controller only. Can we use that `$scope` in other controllers of the other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each controller will have their own `$scope`. Even though there's a `$rootScope` that all the controllers of the page will have access, this is not the recommended approach since it's like a global variable container for the app module. The preferred way would be to use custom services.

**Using $rootScope:**

```
$rootScope.value = "shared value using $rootScope";
```

This can be accessed in any views or controllers as `$root.value` and `$rootScope.value` respectively.

**Using Custom Service:**

```
$scope.shareCustom = function() {
  CustomService.value = "shared value using CustomService";
};
```

This can be accessed in any controller injecting `CustomService` and attaching it to its `$scope`.

**Snippets :**

```
.controller('AnyCtrl', function ($scope, CustomService) {
  $scope.customService = CustomService;
});

<p>{{customService.value}}</p>
```

I have made [**Plunker Demo**](https://embed.plnkr.co/0GwxaA8FwjyN8FcmeDYs/) to illustrate both of these ways of sharing data.

Answer (score 1):

No you **cannot**. When you move to another page new controller get initialized.

In order to use same variable try considering sharing the variable using factory/service. You can also use $rootScope but its not a recommended way.

Comment: when we change to other page does the scope in first page change?

Comment: what do you mean by scope in first page, no it does not. it will be kept in that state